# SmartGWT JSOHelper cleanProperties undefined

Tags: json, datasource, smartgwt

In Using SmartGWT and RESTDataSource, I am submitting through a form and a grid.
Occasionally, I get creap in the dataMap that I don't want.  These bogus values:
_module, _ref, _select, _component, _listGrid, any of these items often come with into the dataMap.

In the transformRequest, when I have my JSON to send, I can manually use com.smartgwt.client.util.JSOHelper to deleteattributes if they exist.
And it seems there used to be a method called "cleanProperties" which doesn't seem to exist.
If I don't clean out these bogus properties, then my RESTful web-service fails because the JSON I am sending back does not conform to the object the controller is expecting.

I am using SmartGWT 4.0, and would be willing to go to SmartGWT 4.1 to solve this issue.

Is there anything else I need to do, or how can I solve this problem.   I can provide any code if need be, but it seems like it should be an easy problem to fix.

Thanks!

Comment: Have your tried [JSOHelper#cleanProperties()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/util/JSOHelper.html#cleanProperties%28com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject,%20boolean%29)?

Comment: Are you kidding me?  That is the exact method I am trying to use!!!!  I know about this method, and I am trying to use it, but in SmartGWT 4.0, it looks like this method is NOT available as I previously stated.   In my code, it says this method, in this class is undefined.  In some of the source code I have seen, it looks like this block of code for this method was commented out.